# positional argument follow keyword argument

Tags: csv

There are code below:

```
    CSV_COLUMNS = ['survived', 'sex', 'age', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 
    'fare', 'class', 'deck', 'embark_town', 'alone']
    
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(..., column_names=CSV_COLUMNS, ...)
```

when I run this code on my tensorflow object that I was followed with google tensorflow guide book, I got a Type Error: positional argument follow keyword argument.

when I tried to debug it as following

```
CSV_COLUMNS = ['survived', 'sex', 'age', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'fare', 'class', 'deck', 'embark_town', 'alone']
    
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(..., ..., column_names=CSV_COLUMNS)
```

then I got another Type Error: make_csv_dataset_v2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'batch_size'

finally, I changed it again

```
CSV_COLUMNS = ['survived', 'sex', 'age', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'fare', 'class', 'deck', 'embark_town', 'alone']
    
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(..., column_names=CSV_COLUMNS, batch_size = 64)
```

another type error: 'ellipsis' object is not iterable

I am gonna crazy!

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question somewhat. Try to focus on one problem, if you want to show several examples that have different error messages, please provide a clear example of exactly the call that gives you the error and the actual error message.

Comment: Thank you, I already changed my formatting

Answer (score 0):

An error "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument" (I don't think that was a `TypeError` like you suggested) means that you're using arguments to a function call like this:

```
some_function(10, b=20, 30)
```

Note how the middle parameter is explicitly named with a keyword 'b', but the 1st and 3rd are not, they rely on being in the correct position.

Doing that, using a keyword argument before you've assigned all the positional arguments you need, is not allowed. Since Python does allow positional use of keyword arguments, there's a few ways to fix this. For example:

```
def some_function(a, b, c=0, d=1):
    pass


# these are OK
some_function(10, 20)
some_function(10, b=20)
some_function(10, 20, 30)
some_function(10, 20, d=40)

# this is not OK
some_function(10, b=20, 30)
# this is the fix:
some_function(10, b=20, c=30)
```

For that same example function, if you were to call it like this:

```
some_function(10, c=30)
```

You'd get the second error you mention: "TypeError: some_function() missing 1 required positional argument". This makes sense, because what value does `b` now have?

The last error message "'ellipsis' object is not iterable" is far more specific. There's a special object in Python, called `Ellipsis`, also written as `...`. It is not an iterable (i.e. you can't do something like `for x in ...`) and the error you're getting probably means it gets assigned to some parameter which expects an iterable to be passed.

You should probably very carefully examine what arguments you are passing and to what parameters you expect those arguments to be assigned and once you fix that, this error will no longer appear either. Going into why it would be caused exactly is too much of a red herring.

It's possible you actually want or need to use the ellipsis, to tell an object or function to auto-fill some parameters and avoid passing a number of arguments, but in that case you need to be very specific about the libraries you're using, because that's not standard Python behaviour, but specific to what happens in those libraries and you should probably refer to the documentation for them.